# Creating a Logical network diagram

Tags: networking, vpn, infrastructure

Im a student and I have been assigned the task of creating a logical network diagram for the following scenario

There are 2 buildings, the first is the head office and the second is the branch.

The data centre is in the head office, it contains domain controller, mail server, file server and a web server. it provides wired and wireless access to the staff.

the branch building is new and it does not have a network.

The two buildings must be connected using a VPN connection.

The branch building will not have any servers but just network devices that will provide the connectivity, the users in the branch building will be connected to the head office over the VPN.

I had created a diagram based on this scenario, but my teacher rejected it saying that it does not follow Cisco hierarchical Model and the servers were not placed correctly in the diagram.

I just wanted some help in this matter so that I Can create my network diagram correctly.

If anyone could upload a picture of how the logical diagram should be for this scenario will be helpful, any other resources would also be great.

Comment: Here's a link with some pictures explaining the Cisco hierchical model: http://www.semsim.com/ccna/ccna-study-guide.asp?ain=57

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Cisco Packet Tracer**. 
It's a a network simulation program, which can be used to understand various concepts of networking with simulation. It can be used to design a network by connecting various networking devices and running various troubleshooting tests to check the connectivity and communication between different networking devices. Packet tracer can be used to understand the use of different networking devices appropriately and the difference in their working. As it is costly to buy different networking equipments while learning networking, thus Packet Tracer can be used to understand the computer networks. ([Source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_Tracer)). 
I have personally used this software, it's very easy to simulate a network. Download it with tutorial package, which will be very helpful to learn some basics. 
 Download link: http://www.cs.rpi.edu//~kotfid/packettracer/